# c# web browser and statustext to show hyperlink

Tags: c#, hyperlink, browser

So I have a custom windows form with a tabbed browser. I want to be able to see the hoovered hyperlink in the status bar. I have searched everywhere but nothing yet.

I checked the MSDN under the web browser class which led me to the [`StatusTextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.statustext.aspx).

So in my code I have

```
wb.StatusTextChanged += MainWindow_StatusChange;
```

then

```
private void MainWindow_StatusChange(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
     this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = wb.StatusText;
}
```

Well, the `tool.StripStatusLabel2.Text` is empty.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have subscribed the wrong event.

Do this...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.StatusTextChanged += new EventHandler(wb_StatusTextChanged);
    wb.Navigate("http://www.google.de");
}

void wb_StatusTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = ((WebBrowser) sender).StatusText;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, so reason being if I understand correct, my issue was that it was creating a new instant of the browser which of course would be blank